# Find the integrating factor and solve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find an integrating factor and solve
$(2x^2y + x)\,dy + (xy^2 + y)\,dx = 0$

I checked if it was exact, which it wasn't.

Then I found

$M/Y$ to be $xy + 1$

$N/Y$ to be $2xy + 1,$ but when I tried to put it in the form of

$n N/X - mM/Y$ I got $-2xy,$ which didn't really tell me much about the value of $n$ and $m.$

So I tried over by multiplying the original equation by $x^ny^m$ and didn't get two linear equations at the end but two equations, which still had $xy$ terms and am stuck now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Let's do your $x^ny^m$ and see where we get:
$$\underbrace{\left(2x^{n+2}y^{m+1}+x^{n+1}y^m\right)}_{\partial_x}\,dy+\underbrace{\left(x^{n+1}y^{m+2}+x^ny^{m+1}\right)}_{\partial_y}\,dx=0 $$
\begin{align*}
2(n+2)x^{n+1}y^{m+1}+(n+1)x^ny^m&\overset{\text{set}}{=}(m+2)x^{n+1}y^{m+1}+(m+1)x^ny^m \\
2(n+2)xy+n+1&=(m+2)xy+m+1 \\
2(n+2)xy+n&=(m+2)xy+m.
\end{align*}
So the terms not multiplying $xy$ will have to be equal, forcing $n=m$. Can we get the coefficients of $xy$ to line up? We'd need
\begin{align*}
2(n+2)&=n+2\\
2n+4&=n+2\\
n&=-2=m.
\end{align*}
It works! Evidently, the integrating factor is
$$\mu(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2y^2}. $$
If you multiply through by this, you'll find the equation is now exact.

Comment: I got the same equation as you of $2(n+2)xy + n = (m+2)xy + m$.



I didn't realize you would then set the non multiplying terms and solve. I was expecting I would get something not including xy.
Thanks!